# How many number of anime sales in Japan is considered as profitable?

Tags: anime-production

I was really curious so I wanted to know: How much sales of anime in Japan is considered profitable? By sales I mean the DVD or something like that.
I heard that anime season or continuation is based on the sales in Japan so, any guess?

Comment: Might be related: [Is the “Manabi Line” a correct way for estimating anime profit/loss?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9238)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*That depends and the answer will vary per anime because the cost of making one season of anime varies*. However, from [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interest/2015-08-13/anime-insiders-share-how-much-producing-a-season-costs/.91536),

> According to Masamune Sakaki, a CG creator in the anime industry, an average 13-episode anime season costs around 250 million yen (or $2 million).

If we take that as an example and say that each Blu-ray would cost at around 5000 yen, which is more or less the case if you look at [some sites selling them](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp), the anime would have to sell at around 50000 Blu-rays for [break-even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break-even), and even more for profit and a budget for another season. This is only if they're trying to recover costs based on Blu-ray sales alone, but anime tend to have other merchandise you can buy aside from Blu-ray.